# What book has human colonies at war against a (possibly bat-like) alien race?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, spaceship, military-sf

The story takes place in the future; humans have colonized our galaxy but they encounter an alien race with which peace is impossible. Colonies start the war but Earth doesn't help them and decides to block the solar system entirely with space mines so nobody can enter. Decades pass and humans from the colonies are losing the battle against the aliens because they lack battleships, and the only way to win against the aliens is to fight the same way but with more battleships than them.

Finally, one day Earth sends a ship with a very small crew. All the crew member have developed special powers, like tactical genius, telepathy, and telekinesis. This ship goes to the planet of origin of the aliens and thanks to their power manages to convince the alien leader to attack Earth massively.

> Half of the alien army goes to Earth. Too late they realize it’s a trap: the sun or Earth (not sure which) explodes, half of the alien army is wiped out, and then the human colonies can win the war. Earth has been sacrificed for the fate of the human race.

I think the alien race look like giant bats.

I think the author is American and the book was released from 1990 to 2005.

What book is this?

Comment: yes It's the book I was looking for! thx

Answer (score 7):

This could be "[The Solarians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Solarians)" by Norman Spinrad, originally published in 1966.

Per wikipedia

> The novel takes places centuries in the future when humanity has
> colonized many star systems. Another race, the Duglaari or "Doogs" is
> slowly conquering human systems, herding the inhabitants into barren
> areas where they simply starve to death. The two races have
> approximately equal technologies, and space battles are decided by
> superior numbers, with the Doogs always having the advantage.
>
> **The colonists are awaiting the emergence of saviors from "Fortress Sol", the Solar System, which has been closed off to all ships since the early days of the war. Before sealing themselves off with billions of space mines and robot ships, the Solarians, as they are known to the colonists, promised to re-emerge with an answer to the numeric superiority of the Duglaari.**
>
> In appearance the Duglaari are roughly humanoid except for **large eyes, fur, and bat-wing ears which move to express emotion**
>
> The Solarians take Palmer to Fortress Sol, behind all its defenses,
> and tour the system so he can see Earth for the last time. The
> Duglaari fleet arrives and penetrates the defences, unleashing massive
> bombardments that destroy all the habitable planets. When all seems
> lost, a stardrive in a ship on Mercury is activated, and Sol explodes,
> annihilating the Doog fleet. Suddenly the Solarian scheme becomes
> clear to Palmer. By goading the Doogs into risking a large part of the
> fleet, they have destroyed so many ships that from now on, the
> colonists will always have the advantage. Palmer's humiliation was a
> necessary part of the deception. He believes that Earth sacrificed
> itself to save the colonies.

[image]

Comment: YES IT'S THE BOOK!!! thank you so much!!! Now i realized I read a new release of 2001!

Comment: I'm the one on the left; http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_Us9tJsr4ZjY/TNYjjMgqDMI/AAAAAAAAALM/K6qnUVM5naA/s1600/We+are+amazing.png